# SSIS Data flow task (SQl -> CSV) data formatting issue

Tags: mysql, ssis, export-to-csv, ssis-2012

In SSIS, I have a data flow task which uses a data flow task to get data from SQL and save it in CSV file( using flat file connection manager).

In this, I have a column which will give me values like (case1 and case 2 are just for reference.)

Case 1: `2333,376677`

Case 2: `E37777,77777`

In first case, I am not getting the `,` in Csv. It is giving me `2333376677`.

In case 2, it is working fine.

In connection manager, I am delimiting with text qualifier as `"`.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: What is the data type of this column and what is the locale and encoding you are using for your target flat file?

Comment: The data type of the column is nvarchar and I am using Unicode string (WSTR) in the csv

Comment: Using an OleDb Source as the SQL data source, I'm not able to reproduce this issue. To me, this looks like your column is treated as a decimal and the target locale removing the `,` as a thousand separator.

Comment: Yes i am using OLED source and flat file destination. In the source i am having multiple columns in which the mentioned column is one among them

Comment: Did you check the *Input and Output Properties* in the *Advanced Editor* (right-click OLE DB Source)? At some point, this value is not treated as WSTR.

Comment: Thanks Filburt.. it is WSTR everywhere and we even used data conversion to convert it to WSTR.. and in advanced editor, the type for that column is WSTR

Comment: Any other chance?? Should we use any other data type to restore the , between numbers as in the source?

Comment: Best approach to get to the root cause is usually to create [mcve]: Create a new Data Flow with an OLE DB Source that only selects this column by query and connect directly to a Flat File Destination. Isolate any possible interferences (select from table instead of view if this is the case for you).